# Wrong TableView header width when using TableView.CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY

Tags: java, javafx, tableview

It's actualy a known bug and steel opened a bug report for JavaFX, which you may found 
[here](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8090112).

**Description is:**

When ColumnResizePolicy is setted to CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY and table have data that is not fit in available tableview's height (vertical scroll is visible) then headers have improper width - but only when TableView is not focused. When TableView get focus then headers are getting proper width.

The problem is, I really need to fix it somehow, but i can't find any workaround to do that.

**I tried:**

`refresh()`
and just "jumping" out and in

```
otherGUIObject.requestFocus();
tableView.requestFocus(); //or getSelectionModel().Select(0)    
otherGUIObject.requestFocus();
```

also

```
tableView.setColumnResizePolicy(TableView.UNCONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY);
tableView.setColumnResizePolicy(TableView.CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY);
```

But nothing seems to work. Have someine any ideas?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the correct track: you should call `requestFocus()` on the `TableView`.

The problem with the following snippet (from your question)

```
otherGUIObject.requestFocus();
tableView.requestFocus(); //or getSelectionModel().Select(0)    
otherGUIObject.requestFocus();
```

is that when you call `requestFocus()`, the [focusedProperty](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#focusedProperty--) of the `Node` is set to `true` as expected, but it does not mean, that the control actually gets focused on the GUI (the layout is updated) - as it is only updated when the JavaFX application thread has time to update it. In the snippet you make three `requestFocus` calls in a row: the first two will be optimized, therefore only the last one is executed (most probably).

The solution is to call the [`requestLayout`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Parent.html#requestLayout--) method on the `TableView` after the focus is requested to ensure that the focus is updated on the GUI too. Afterwards you can set the focus on any other `Node` (in the example I have used [`focusOwnerProperty`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Scene.html#focusOwnerProperty) of `Scene` to get which `Node` is currently selected, then after the `TableView` was focused, I focus this `Node` again).

**Example**

```
// The current focus owner on the Scene
Node focusOwner = scene.getFocusOwner();

table.requestFocus();
table.requestLayout();

// Request focus on the currently focused Node
if(focusOwner != null)
    focusOwner.requestFocus();
else
    // request focus on any Node you want
    textField.requestFocus();
```

Comment: Great answer. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I tried the solution that @DVarga suggests and it is not working for me. When my application performs the *table.requestFocus()* and then *table.requestLayout()* nothing happens apparently. It is probably because the table scroll bar is added after your code is executed, therefore the kew to this issue is running the code @DVarga proposes using *Platform.runLater()* to ensure the focus is performed once the rest of layout operations finish. I found two solutions which are working for me:

### Example 1

```
tableView.setColumnResizePolicy(TableView.CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY);
Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            tableView.refresh();

        }
});
```

### Example 2

```
tableView.setColumnResizePolicy(TableView.CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY);
Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            tableView.requestFocus();

        }
});
```

However, I realize that the tableview focus effect can be appreciated for about one second after the javafx scene is loaded. I do not know if there is a more elegant solution.