# Wrong tableview column width

Tags: java, javafx

I got a problem which described [there(bug)](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8090112) and this bug is never fixed

My table view with count of rows less then visible count(vertical scroll-bar is not visible) everything works fine, and i can set prefWidth of column. But when scroll-bar is visible and rows count are >~40, tableview automatically set columns size to CONSTRAINED and ignore prefWidth property. I have seen the same question [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38264482/wrong-tableview-header-width-when-using-tableview-constrained-resize-policy), but i didn't undestand the answer.

Can you, please, explain existing answer more expanded, or help me how to fix this bug by other ways. I will be very appreciate for any help!

[Image Scrollbar exists](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9WXPf.jpg)

[Image Without scrollbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y4xva.jpg)

Comment: From his explanation, you need to `table.requestLayout` first to get latest GUI. Then do `textField.requestFocus`.

Comment: @bejond
`getFocusOwner()` invoke NullPointer for me
i typed something like that
`tableView.requestFocus();
tableView.requestLayout();
createFrom(textField).requestFocus();`
in initialize method and it doesnt help me. thanks for respond

Comment: It says requestLayout() first, then requestFocus()

Comment: @bejond , it doesn't make any change, maybe i don't know where i need to paste this code, after columns filling and making all handlers and listeners?